# Android 4.0 and above: after installing my application how to detect the phone uses android security lock .?

Tags: android

My app uses sensitive data of patients . I will have to allow the user 
to open the app one and only if he uses android's any default security lock(pattern or pin or any) . How will I get the phone security status. if it does not use any locking mechanism to lock the phone i will have to enforce him to lock and exit the app.

Answer (score 1):

The [device management APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) allow you to determine the general security status of the device, such as [`getPasswordQuality()` on `DevicePolicyManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getPasswordQuality%28android.content.ComponentName%29).

Comment: Do you have any sample or example ... I am a beginner ..  I really dunno how to use

Comment: @user17852: Not for your specific scenario. Here are a couple of sample projects for the device admin APIs in general: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DeviceAdmin